# Peek & pop does not trigger only on the last cell

Tags: ios, swift, 3dtouch, ios-extensions, peek-pop

I have a ProfileVC that contain a list.
I can click on any of the row cell will show peek and pop feature.

**ProfileVC.swift**

I added the extention

```
extension ProfileViewController : UIViewControllerPreviewingDelegate {
    
    func detailViewController(for indexPath: IndexPath) -> ProfileDetailViewController {
        guard let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ProfileDetailViewController") as? ProfileDetailViewController else {
            fatalError("Couldn't load detail view controller")
        }
        
        let cell = profileTableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! ProfileTableViewCell
        
        // Pass over a reference to the next VC
        vc.title   = cell.profileName?.text
        vc.cpe     = loginAccount.cpe
        vc.profile = loginAccount.cpeProfiles[indexPath.row - 1]
        
        consoleLog(indexPath.row - 1)
        
        //print("3D Touch Detected !!!",vc)
        
        return vc
    }
    
    func previewingContext(_ previewingContext: UIViewControllerPreviewing, viewControllerForLocation location: CGPoint) -> UIViewController? {
        if let indexPath = profileTableView.indexPathForRow(at: location) {
            
            // Enable blurring of other UI elements, and a zoom in animation while peeking.
            previewingContext.sourceRect = profileTableView.rectForRow(at: indexPath)
            
            return detailViewController(for: indexPath)
        }
        
        return nil
    }
    
    //ViewControllerToCommit
    func previewingContext(_ previewingContext: UIViewControllerPreviewing, commit viewControllerToCommit: UIViewController) {
        
        // Push the configured view controller onto the navigation stack.
        navigationController?.pushViewController(viewControllerToCommit, animated: true)
    }
    
}
```

Then, in the same file **ProfileVC.swift** in `viewDidLoad()` I registered it

```
if (self.traitCollection.forceTouchCapability == .available){
    print("-------->", "Force Touch is Available")
    registerForPreviewing(with: self, sourceView: view)
}
else{
    print("-------->", "Force Touch is NOT Available")
}
```

---

## Result

I have no idea why I can not click on the **4th** cell.

The **last** cell of the row does not trigger Peek & Pop.

How would one go about and debug this further?

Comment: What does the debugger show?  Is the delegate function called but the `if let` fails, or is the function not called?

Comment: Which function you referring to? Also, do I need to add anything in my `ProfileDetailVC.swift` ?

Comment: If you add more cells does it still fail only on the last one?

Comment: @GaloTorresSevilla : I can add one more profile, and find out. Let me do it now.

Comment: I mean the `previewingContext(_,location:)` function.

Comment: @Paulw11 Let me do a print statement in there, and see if it got printed.

Comment: @GaloTorresSevilla : Yes, I can reproduce it, add nother profile, only the bottom one is not triggeting Peek & Pop.

Comment: Or set a breakpoint and use the debugger.  If you don't know how to use the debugger in Xcode, now is the time to learn.  It is an enormously powerful tool.

Comment: @Paulw11 : I added a print `print("_ previewingContext location")` I got it to print : https://i.imgur.com/P2oIWyl.png

Comment: My print statement inside `if let indexPath` never get executed only for that last cell. https://i.imgur.com/c0Okks5.png

Comment: Right, so the most likely conclusion is that the `if let` is falling through (again, the debugger would show you this straight away!). What source view do you use when you call `registerForPreviewing` ?

Comment: @Paulw11 I called `registerForPreviewing` in same **ProfileVC** inside `viewDidLoad()`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186943/discussion-between-paulw11-and-kyo).

Comment: When registering for previewing you should pass your tableview as the source view instead of the view controller's view

Comment: @dan : Can you please answer your suggestion so I can try ? I'm still new on iOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are registering your view controller's root `view` as the source view for the peek context. As a result, the `CGPoint` that is passed to previewingContext(_  viewControllerForLocation:)` is in the coordinate space of that view.

When you try and retrieve the corresponding row from your table view the point will actually be offset from the corresponding point in the table view's `frame` based on the relative position of the table view in the root view.

This offset means that a corresponding row can’t be retrieved for the last row in the table; `indexPathForRow(at:)` returns `nil` and your function returns without doing anything.

You might also find that if you force touch towards the bottom of a cell you actually get a peek for the next row.

You could translate the `CGPoint` into the table view’s frame, but it is simpler to just specify your tableview as the source view when you register for previewing:

```
if (self.traitCollection.forceTouchCapability == .available){
    print("-------->", "Force Touch is Available")
    registerForPreviewing(with: self, sourceView: self.profileTableView)
}
else{
    print("-------->", "Force Touch is NOT Available")
}
```

Comment: Amazing answer, works perfectly - You're a true life saver. 